# Appropriate configuration of headers for specific back-button browser behaviour

Tags: php, caching, browser, header

I'm developing a project which requires me to allow users to be able to click Back button in their browser and return to the previous page which should be loaded from their cache.

I've been experimenting with Header: Cache-Control etc, and this behaviour worked. However, a new problem appeared: users on shared networks and behind cache/proxy servers, received mixed sessions - i.e they were logged in as some other users.

I'm looking for ways to both allow back button to load cached content, but to be sure that sessions will not mix.

Ebay and other large sites are doing this and I think there is a proper combination of Cache headers that should be sent to user in order to achieve this.

Comment: Wait, you mean users find they're logged in on session they never owned? That would be a terrible security issue..

Comment: Also, in general you don't cache dynamically generated content on the client side, which is what you did with those headers. Usually you'd cache the content on the server and serve it as static content without chaching on the client.

Comment: Users found they're logged in on session they never owned, but only when behind LAN or proxy.

Appropriate behaviour I want: 
No requests get cached 
However initiating a back button in browser, loads content from your own browser cache (because that's a content you've already loaded).

Comment: Please read my second comment, it should answer your question.